# roslaunch reinstallation

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

While I was trying to fix my rqt problem (but that's another post) I
`sudo apt purge rqt` and then `sudo apt autoremove` and update. Now I have broken apparently `roslaunch` :/

Here are the subsequent  commands and their outputs:

```
roscore

The program 'roscore' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python-roslaunch
```

then:

```
sudo apt install python-roslaunch

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-roslaunch : Depends: python-roslib but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

then:

```
sudo apt install python-roslib

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-roslib : Depends: catkin but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And it goes on like this for

sudo apt install catkin --> Depends: python-catkin-pkg but it is not going to be installed

```
sudo apt install python-catkin-pkg
```

where it says its already there:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-catkin-pkg is already the newest version (0.3.1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

What is wrong with that?
Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260796/roslaunch-reinstallation/) by [qor qor](https://answers.ros.org/users/30217/qor-qor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-05-01

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brausebart](https://answers.ros.org/users/30414/brausebart/) on 2017-05-16**:
I have the exact same problem and also didnt find any solution for that yet. Would be glad to get some hints..

**Comment by [mago3421](https://answers.ros.org/users/30460/mago3421/) on 2017-05-19**:
I have this same problem. I've tried steps proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) but with no luck.

**Comment by [INDAR98](https://answers.ros.org/users/35428/indar98/) on 2018-05-24**:
I want to *uninstall ros which is with the same error*

anyone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has your environment been set up properly? E.g.

```
echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

See http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu.

I believe that it should be looking for ros-kinetic-roslaunch, instead of python-roslaunch

---

Originally posted by [dvlierop](https://answers.ros.org/users/30874/dvlierop/) with karma: 46 on 2017-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahmed alaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/33531/ahmed-alaa/) on 2018-02-02**:
thanks dvlierop it works for me